# Wordpress - The7 Template - On every page I have 4 Warnings and do not know how to disable it in menu or php site/content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have a problem with my Wordpress site, more specifically, The7 template. On every page, including the main page at the bottom of page below footer I have 4 Warnings which are the same:

***“Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ‘wp_filter_content_tags’ not found or invalid function name in on line”***

I do not know how to solve it/turn it off. Could you tell me which PHP page or what exactly cause this problem to appear? It’s really annoying. Due to the fact that it is in the main body and not in any div/b/p/etc. tag I cannot hide it with CSS just for a while.

Kind regards
Peter

Answer (score 0):

## Hiding error reporting on prod

On prod you want to avoid showing errors, due to security and user experience reasons. To achieve this, in PHP you can run

```
error_reporting(0);
```

or, even better, in **php.ini**, you can have this line

```
error_reporting = off
```

## What the error means

The error tells you that a `function` is to be called by name, but it does not exist. [wp_filter_content_tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_content_tags/) does not exist in your context.

## Solution to the error

Even though you have hidden error reporting on prod, you still need to show errors on dev and that function might do something very useful. From the doc you can see that it's located in **wp-includes/media.php**. So, if you do not need to call this `function`, then search for its calls and remove them. If you need this function, then `require` or `include` it into your files. If, for some reason you cannot remove this `function` (for ex. you do not want to hack a template that might have some versions in the future), but the `function`/file is not helpful for you, then you can implement a `function` with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for answer. I used it to find solution and in my case there is a need to change wp-config.php a little bit. It means to add these specific lines to code:

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false)
```

In my case it worked and no more errors / warnings showed on every / main pages.

Kind Regards
Peter